# Simplifying $\nabla\cdot(\vec{F}\circ\vec{G})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator

I'm going through various [vector calculus identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities) and I was curious that they listed no way of expressing $\nabla\cdot(\vec{F}\circ\vec{G})$, where $\vec{F} : \mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\vec{G} : \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$.

Using the total derivative formula, we can derive the sum formula
$$
\nabla\cdot (\vec{F}\circ\vec{G}) = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{\partial G_j}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j}\circ G\right)
$$
but I can't find a way to express this in a simpler, non-sum fashion. I had the impression it was some expression involving the Jacobian, seeing as all the partial derivatives of all the components of $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{G}$ are involved, but I can't find a way of combining $\text{J}_{\vec{G}}$ and $\text{J}_{\vec{F}}\circ G$ that results in a scalar.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about $\text{tr}(J_GJ_F)$ (where each of the jacobians are evaluated at the point corresponding to the chain rule)?

This describes exactly that sum, but using only the Jacobian matrices of each vector field.

Comment: I can't believe I skipped over this. It occurred to me that the trace might be the direction to go, but I thought the chances of it working were too low to justify experimenting. Thank you for your help!